# How do I create a migration for a content type?

Tags: drupal-8

I wanted to migrate 3 fields to the *Article* content type. So I want to know the initial step to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the way you want to migrate the data, depends on how you do it. Also, is this a migration from a previous version? Basically you would create those fields in the new database, and using the data type you choose for export (JSON being the easiest) you'll setup your source, process, and destination module/plugin to manage the content. You can find this info [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview). Then define the field attributes and after exporting the data Drush will pretty much handle the rest.

Start by downloading and installing migrate_plus and migrate_tools into the destination site.

1. Create new fields in destination site.
2. Identify source export type.
3. Export data.
4. Setup module with process (if needed) and destination configuration.
5. Load module in new site, following source type directive
6. Run Drush migrate commands to manage the import.

As I said JSON has been the easiest I have found and is done fairly quickly, setting up the module will be the most time spent but there are enough community modules out there to support you.

Don't forget, always back up, but luckily if using Drush it can always revert back the migration for you in case, just good practice.

Good luck.